# Excel VBA compare 2 listbox on multi-column

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, compare

I'm trying to make a simple VBA UserForm for checking 2 ListBox but with 2 condition

1. check the product number
2. if product number is ok the check Quantity of the product is ok or no

[My user form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHlor.png)

This picture is shows the code that I find (that I searched here and little change it) is just remove the duplicate. And of course I know the code is just checking 1 column of each ListBox.

But after long search and try I cant find any ways to check 
listbox1 column2 with listbox2 column1 
      THEN if its equal
check listbox1 column 4 is equal to listbox2 colum 2

It's a simple inventory app that I'm trying to make to myself.
And the listbox2 is gonna fill by some barcode scanner.

```
Dim obj As Object
Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")    

'1st ListBox
For i = 1 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Not obj.Exists(CStr(ListBox1.List(i, 1))) Then
        obj.Add CStr(ListBox1.List(i, 1)), vbNullString
    End If
Next
'2nd ListBox
For i = 1 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If Not obj.Exists(CStr(ListBox2.List(i, 0))) Then
'add unique of list 2
     obj.Add ListBox2.List(i, 0), vbNullString
   Else

'delet duplicte of list 1
      obj.Remove ListBox2.List(i, 0)
    End If
Next

'add unique list to 3rd ListBox
Dim Key As Variant
     ListBox3.List = obj.Keys()
    lblerr.Caption = ListBox2.ListCount / 2
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do a little clearer?

Comment: listbox1 is populated by a query froma folder that 1 put my excel file there everday.

Comment: so i can read my invoces from this userform. then populate listbox2 with scan barcode and number of products on warehouse . then with button( err check ) compare my invoice(lisbox1 column 2) and products scan (listbox cloumn 1) if they are same then check number of this product in invice(listbox 1 column 4) is same number of exiting real products scan from warehouse (listbox 2 column 2)  if every item is not same so list box 3 shows the errors .simply  (inventory application) thank you

Comment: if (listbox1 column 2 = listbox2 column1) and (listbox1 column 4=listbox2 column2) then ok else not ok